# What is the meaning of "It is possible to map objects in the problem domain to those in the program"?

Tags: c++

I have read the above statement in the OOP C++ balagurusamy book. This statement is written under the topic of "benefits of OOP." I have tried to understand this but i am not getting. so can anyone help me to sort out this?

Comment: Real dog -> `class dog;`, etc...

Comment: Find another book.

Comment: Thank you. Can you give little bit explanation on this?

Answer (score 0):

This means that you can associate a relationship(kind of) between real life objects and objects in a program. For example,

**EXAMPLE 1**

Lets say you have a Factory of different Vehicles and the vehicles have different attributes like name, mfd date, number of tires, size etc etc.

Now you may(can) implement this real life problem(scenario) in a program as follows:

```
class Vehicle
{
    ...constructors and other code here
    std::string name;
    float date;
    std::string color;
    ...//and so on
}
class Car: public Vehicle
{
    //here you can add type specific code, that is code that is specific to Car
}
class Factory
{
 std::vector<Vehicles> myVehicles;
}
```

So you're mapping a real life scenario to the domain of the program. Obviously there are many more examples, i have given just one of them.

The reason for doing this is that now you can handle different things about a particular factory and other real life objects. In this case a factory object has a `std::vector` of Vehicle's which represent the different vehicles that this particular Factory has. Simlarly you can have another factory lets say at Ohio which contain its own vehicle. So basically **you are modelling real life problem** through a program.

Answer (score 0):

Generally it is all about using basic OOP principals in a scope of a program design. Programs are writing for human needs (domain scope). For example you need to print an essay, and you need a program for typing i.e. text editor. This  text editor should have contain some user interface. This user interface can be logically split on some components like: text area, menu, menu times, status line, toolbar, buttons in tool bar, select file dialog for open and save operation etc.
To implement all of those components in your program, you can logically split it on sort of classes which were encapsulate data and code related to each component. As well as those classes expected to have some common behavior like show/hide, move etc. So you can implement it with a common class - widget. Then inherit all component classes from widget parent, so that you don't have to duplicate common code for: show, hide and move operations for all your components.

In menu you have an menu items, like open, save, exit etc. All items are similar so they can be implements by the same class in the same time, when you click on it operation should differ, i.e. open and save should open a select file dialog and then open or save file, when exit should save file and then close application. How to inject this operation inside a class without creating a sub-class for each menu item. You can create an fully virtual abstract class called Action with one fully virtual method, like perform. Then you can add a pointer on reference member into MenuIntem class. Then you can create a classes inherits Action, override fully virtual member - perform. Implementation of this perform will do some exact operation - like open file, safe file etc. And then you can inject reference on implementation into MenuItems objects. I.e. something like this:

```
struct Bounds {
  std::size_t left, top, width, height; 
}

class Widget {
   Widget(const Widget&) = delete;
   Widget& oprator=(const Widget&) = delete;
public:
   Widget(Bounds& bounds) noexcept:
     bounds_(bounds);
   {} 
   virtual ~Widget() = default; 
   void move(std::size_t left, std::size_t top) 
   {
      bounds_.left = left;
      bounds_.top = top;
      draw();   
   }
   virtual void draw()  {
     // some platform specific implementation
   }
   virtual void show() {
    // some platform specific implementation
   }
   virtual void hide() {
    // some platform specific implementation
   }
private:
  bounds bounds_;
}
    
class Window: public Widget {
// some implementation
}

class SelectFileDialog: public Window {
// Some implemenation
}
....
class TextArea:public Widet 
{
// some implementation
}
class StatusLine:public Widet
{
// some implementation
} 

class Button: public Widget 
{
public:
   Button(Bounds& bounds, const std::string& caption):
     Widget(),
     caption_(caption)
   {}
   virtual void onClick() = 0;  
private:
  std::string caption_;  
}
    
class Action {
  Action(const Action&) = delete;
  Action& operator=(Action&) = delete; 
public:
   virtual ~Action() = default;
   virtual void perform() = 0;
}

class MenuItem: public Button {
public:
  MenuItem(const std::string& cation, const std::shared_ptr<Action> action):
    Button({0,0,100,30},cation),
    action_(action)
  {}
  virtual void onClick() override 
  {
    // real app should use some arguments
    action_->perform();
  }
private:
   std::shared_ptr<Action> action_;
}

class SaveFileAction: public Action {
 public:
    void perform() override 
    {
       SelectFileDialog dlg;
       dlg.show();
       // some save implementation   
    }
}


class OpenFileAction: public Action {
 public:
    void perform() override 
    {
       SelectFileDialog dlg;
       dlg.show();
       // some open file implementation   
    }
}

class PrintFileAction: public Action {
 public:
    void perform() override 
    {
       // some print file impementation   
    }
}
....

class MenuBox: public Widget 
{
public:
  MenuBox(Bounds& bounds):
    Widget(bounds) 
  {} 
  void addItem(const std::string& caption, std::shared_ptr<Action> action) 
 {
   items_.emplace_back( std::make_shared<MenuItem>( caption, action ) );
 }
private:
  std::vector< std::shared_ptr<MenuItem> > items_;
}

class MainWinow: public Window
{
public:
  MainWidow():
    Window({ 100, 100, 640, 480})
  {}
  void addComponent(const std::shared_ptr<Widget>&  w) 
  {
    childs_.epmplace_back(w);
  }
  virtual void show() override {
    Window::show(); 
    for(auto w: childs_) {
       w->show();
    }
  }
pivate:
  std::vector< std::shared_ptr<Widgets> > childs_;
}

int main(int argc, const char** argv) {
  std::shared_ptr<MainWidow> w( new MainWindow() );
  ...
  std::shared_ptr<MenuBox> mainMenu(new MenuBox() );
  mainMenu->addItem("Open", std::shared_ptr<Action>(new OpenFileAction()) );
  mainMenu->addItem("Save", std::shared_ptr<Action>(new SaveFileAction()) );
  mainMenu->addItem("Print", std::shared_ptr<Action>(new PrintFileAction()) );
  mainMenu->addItem("Exit", std::shared_ptr<Action>(new ExitAction()) );
  ...
  w->addComponent(mainMenu);
  w->addComponent(textArrea);
  w->addComponent(statusLine);
  ...
  w->show();
  return 0;
}
```

Those this explains all basic OPP principles: encapsulation, aggregation, inheritance and polymorphism.

This is how OOP allow you to organize you application structure and help to reuse code. It is not for free i.e. all this abstractions cost memory and CPU time, for some small console programs OOP may not be needed. For most of complex programs benefits gives you a lot.

There are libraries of reusable classes you can use for different domains.
The most common is C++ standard library with io streams, time, threads etc. For other common scenarios you can look into [boost](https://www.boost.org/)

For graphical user interface there are a log Widget libraries like: [wxWidgets](https://www.wxwidgets.org/), [QT](https://www.qt.io/), [GTK MM](https://www.gtkmm.org/en/), [Fltk](https://www.fltk.org/) and many others.

For video games there are special libraries and additional programs called engines - for example [OGRE](https://www.ogre3d.org/), [Unreal Engine](https://www.unrealengine.com/en-US/) etc.

As well as there are libraries for implementing WEB and file severs, printing, image processing, AI and so one.

All this frameworks use object oriented programming concept to describe problem domain.